# tkinter widget trigger trace function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to call trace of variable manually. See code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

checkbox = None

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()

    global checkbox
    checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(root, command=cmd)
    checkbox.grid()

    root.mainloop()

def cmd():
    print("called")

threading.Thread(target=main).start()

checkbox.cget("command")
# '2032414134664cmd'
```

The `cget` returns `id` of function and `name`.
I found a method to get function but it is not elegant.

```
import ctypes
import re

get_int_re = re.compile(r"(\d+).*")
id_of_command = int(get_int_re.findall(checkbox.cget("command"))[0])
call_wrapper = ctypes.cast(id_of_command, ctypes.py_object).value

function = call_wrapper.__self__.func
print(function)
# <function cmd at 0x000001D9372274C8>
```

Is there any elegant way to get the command of Checkbutton?

Comment: Why not just remember the information separately?

Comment: I have a complex code and I sometimes need the trace. If I want to keep separately, I have to change the logic a lot. Another solution for this wrapping the Checkbox widget and add an attribute named command and hold the trace function in it. I already have two solutions but I just wonder if there is a simple way to do this.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the command associated with a button? I don't see any sort of trace being done here.